# How to run 3000+ PowerBI visuals in One page WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, powerbi

I have 3000+ visuals in the PowerBI account. I can embed them in WordPress using one Plugin. I want to load it in single page using Tabs Nav. I have done using html, jQuery. But the page taking too much time to load, page is not showing any contents, a white blank screen appearing.

Can anyone suggest how to do it in HTML, jQuery?

Thanks

Comment: You should really ask yourself the question what is the point of having 3000+ visuals in one page word press. Power-bi visuals are not images, they are elements with logic..

Comment: @Albert. Yes that is an elements with logic. But I can load it through AJAX. I have achieved 3000 even 30000 visuals in one page using AJAX logic by developed a plugin.